# ffmpeg screen recording file can't be played with video via windows media player

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video, display, vlc-media-player

I'm new to ffmpeg. Recently I have recorded my screen using commmand C:\Users\Totzfreelance\ffmpeg.exe -f dshow -i video="UScreenCapture":audio="Microphone (Realtek High Definition Audio)" output1.mp4

But the result (the output1.mp4) can't be played with video (only sound) with Windows media player but I can play it both sound and video using VLC. What's the problem?

Can you show me the minimalist command how to fix it?

Comment: "What's the problem?" - It sounds as if Windows Media Player doesn't support the default video stream being produced. You may want to try adjusting the format the video/audio is recorded in.

Comment: The solution is I need to add command: -pix_fmt yuv420p to my above command